# Show that the Heaviside function is not weakly differentiable

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Consider the function $$H(x):=\left.\begin{cases}0&\text{, if }x<0\\1&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\Omega:=(-1,1).$$

How can I show that there is no $g\in\mathcal L^2(\Omega)$ with $$\langle H,\varphi'\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}=-\langle g,\varphi\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}\tag1$$ for all $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$?

Clearly, if $g$ exists, then $$\varphi(0)=\langle g,\varphi\rangle\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)\tag2.$$ In particular, $$\varphi(0)=\langle g,\varphi\rangle\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega\setminus\{0\})\tag3.$$

Now we know that $C_c^\infty(\Omega\setminus\{0\})$ is a dense subset of $L^2(\Omega\setminus\{0\})$ and hence $C_c^\infty(\Omega\setminus\{0\})^\perp=\overline{C_c^\infty(\Omega\setminus\{0\})}^\perp=\{0\}$. So, $$g(x)=0\;\;\;\text{for Lebesgue almost all }x\in\Omega\setminus\{0\}\tag4.$$

> But I don't see that this is a contradiction to any of the assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

(Supposing $g$ exists) note that since $\varphi$ is compactly supported, we actually have
$$\varphi(0) = \langle g,\varphi\rangle$$
for all $\varphi$.

Now the main idea is to pick a sequence of functions $\varphi_n$ which breaks this by concentrating around the jump of $H$ at $x=0$.

For example, we can pick smooth functions such that for each $n$,
$$\begin{gather*}
\varphi_n(0)=1 \\
\varphi_n(x) \leq 1 \\
\text{supp}(\varphi) \subseteq [-1/n,1/n]
\end{gather*}$$
You can imagine smoothing out an isosceles-triangle-shaped function with fixed height and decreasing width (in $n$), or use some standard bump function that you know. The important fact you should conclude is that
$$\langle g,\varphi_n\rangle \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please take note of my edit. It is still not clear to me why this is a contradiction. Doesn't it precisely show that $g=0$ is the weak derivative?

Comment: It is a contradiction because $1=\varphi_n(0) = \langle g,\varphi_n\rangle \to 0$. 
Notice that $g\equiv 0$ does not satisfy the needed integration by parts property.

Comment: But your reasoning is right in the sense that: if there _was_ a weak derivative of the step function (which is flat almost everywhere) it looks like it _should_ be 0. But again this won't satisfy the IBP formula, so there (probably) isn't any weak derivative.